# TableView Static Cell: how to add constraint to bottom to the cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I would like to add a constraint on a static cell to keep it at the bottom of the tableView, but in storyboard the constraints are not clickable, is there a way to set it programmatically in Swift? Now there is a white space after my last cell (the one with logout and save button), which doesn't look very nice :

[image: screenshot]

As here the screenshot is white on white it is not really visible, so you might want to save the image to have a proper look.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a tableView. You can achieve this behavior with a collectionView and a custom layout. Another way is to create a separate view and add it as a subview to the tableView at the bottom and add tableView bottom inset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView has a property.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableFooterView
```

> Returns an accessory view that is displayed below the table.

Second option would be adding your custom view and setting up constraints along the lines of:
v:|-[table view]-[custom bottom view]-|

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In `TableView` you can;t do this you can use this approach in `collectionView` or create a `seprateView`